# How do I know the type of a scala function

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to know the type of a scala function in repl. In Haskell it is :t, can anyone tell what it's equivalent in scala?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to know. Once you type in the expression, it tells the type:

```
scala> val f: Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b
f: Int => (Int => Int) = $$Lambda$1143/444402847@2b1a901d
```

If you have an existing value and want to know its type, you use `:type`

```
scala> :type f
Int => (Int => Int)
```

Or as others mention, `:t` also works similar to Haskell:

```
scala> :t f
Int => (Int => Int)
```

Comment: @chunjef Updated.